# Access vector values from a list of vector names

Tags: r, list, loops, variables, vector

I have a set of vector (over 2k) that each contain over 13k entries. I need to loop over each of them to place the data in a txt files for future uses.

So I thought I would create a list, containing the name of all the vector:

```
vector_list <- list()
for (i in 1:Number) {
  vec <- paste("vec", i, sep="")
  assign(vec, data[i,1])
  vector_list[i] <- vec
}
```

Only problem is that when I access the value of `vector_list[-]`, I get the correct name, but it's in between "" so I cannot use it to evaluate the value of the vector whose name is between the "".
when I write

```
  TEST <- vector_list[i]
```

I do not get the value contained in the `veci` (whose name is stored in the `vector_list[i]`) but I get `"veci"`... Any help about this?

I also tryed the command `get` which does not seems to work. For example, if I type `get(vector_list[1])` I get `Error in get(vector_list[1]) : invalid first argument`.
Similar if I use `a<-vector_list[1]` then `get(a)`. Perhaps I am the one misusing the `get` fonction..?

Comment: Use `get`, or even better use a `list` instead of sequentially named variables.

Comment: How did you wind up with all these vectors with sequential names in the first place? This is a bad-code-smell in R. There are likely more functional ways of going this stuff in R but your question leaves out much of the context that would be helpful to suggest alternatives.

Comment: The get command does not seems to work.

Comment: Each vector represent a time step in a FE analysis.

Comment: Well, your example isn't reproducible, so it still looks like a duplicate. My best guess for your bug is that you aren't indexing your list correctly, `vector_list[1]` is a one-element list containing "vec1", but you need to use `vector_list[[1]]` to just get `"vec1"` as a character. (Or use a regular vector, not a list.) The improvement would be to just use a `list` of values not a list of names of variables, i.e., make your entire `for` loop body `vector_list[[i]] <- data[i,1]`. (Or skip the for loop and just do `vector_list = split(data[, 1], 1:nrow(data))`.)

Comment: If you need more explicit help, please [make your example reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).